# Finding extremas

Tags: calculus, optimization

Finding this quite tricky.

$$e^{x}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))=0$$

Solve for $x$.

This is an derivative of the original function: $$f(x)=e^x\cos(x)$$ And I am trying to find the extremas.

Comment: A product is zero only when of the factors is zero. Now, $e^x$ is never zero, so you need $\cos x - \sin x = 0$.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I have derived the function and I am trying to find the extremas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** $$f'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow \cos x=\sin x \quad (\because e^x \neq 0) \Leftrightarrow \tan x =1$$**ANSWER**

> Realize $$\tan x=1 \Leftrightarrow x=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Why not write the solution as $x = \frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That spoils the answer...(so I suggest you delete your comment). I will take your comment into consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your help, just another question how do you get two values that indicate the extremas?

Comment: @ArthurKingLee Notice that the graph looks like the one in the picture [here](http://okwave.jp/qa/q7308484.html), and does not have exactly two extremas. Notice that if $f''(x) \le 0$, then $x$ is the local maxima, whereas if $f''(x) \ge 0$, then $x$ is the local minima.

Comment: @ArthurKingLee Also, if you find my answer helpful you can click on the check below my question to accept it.